# R script to Task Scheduler

Tags: r, batch-processing, windows-task-scheduler

I have an R script that gets data from databases on another server and brings it into my database. I have it saved as "dataimport.R"

I followed a few answers from here and from other websites and created a batch file like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH  --vanilla --slave "C:\dataimport.R"
```

This is not working. The cmd window opens up but the tables are not recreated and I dont get any error. I wanted to run the Task Scheduler to automate the process. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept at it and interestingly the answer to this was this:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" "C:\dataimport.R"
```

I dont know the reason for this but as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had loads of problems with this, but finally managed to get it to work. To be more comprehensive, here are some of the things I've tried (in case one of these work for other persons):

- @echo off, R CMD BATCH C:\myfolder\script.R
- R CMD BATCH C:\myfolder\script.R
- Using the package taskschedulerR (somehow didn't work overnight)
- Used the answer provided above ("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" "C:\dataimport.R")
  and all kinds of variations and combinations off these. (can't remember them all exactly)

What finally worked was:

- Make an R script and save it (C:\myfolder\Test.R for example)
- Through notepad, fill in: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\myfolder\Test.R" (also tried Rscript.exe, didn't work for me).
- in Windows Task Scheduler (v1.0) do 'Create task'
- fill in time triggers.
- in Actions, make an action with Start a program and in the Program/Script line provide the location where your bat script is. C:\myfolder\Test.bat
- in the Start in (optional) line: enter C:\myfolder\

Note: both your .bat file and .R script are in the "C:\myfolder" folder.